# can't cd to any directory inside home when using rbash

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I just set a user to use rbash (I wanted to user to be able to access it's home directory only). However when I try to change sub-directory it always gives me:

> -rbash: cd: restricted

The sub-directory owner is this logged in user, so I don't know why it is restricted. Any idea/help?

Comment: I suggest you open a terminal and type `man rbash`

Answer (score 2):

From the `rbash` man page:

> A restricted shell is used to set up an environment more
>   controlled than the standard shell. It behaves identically
>   to bash with the exception that the following are disallowed
>   or not performed:
>
> - changing directories with cd

`rbash` does not discriminate. It will not allow any `cd`, no matter where you're going. Even if it's a subdirectory of the user's home folder.

IMHO in a real-life situation there really isn't a use for rbash. However, there are other things you can do to prevent users from seeing your stuff. For example, you could run:

```
chmod -R o= $HOME
```

This changes the permissions of all the files in your home folder (`$HOME`) and subdirectories (`-R` = recursively), giving other users no permissions (that's what the `o=` part means) to access, modify, or even *list* files within.

Hope this helps.